# Why is Thunderbird saying I am working offline when Work Offline is not ticked?

Tags: windows-7, email, thunderbird

Thunderbird says "You are currently offline. Do you want to go online to get new messages?"

The menu item File->Work Offline is not checked.

Is there another "offline" setting?

Back story:
I moved my Thunderbird profile from another user to my new account today following the [instructions here](http://support.mozillamessaging.com/kb/Profiles). (it's down as I type). This may be a red herring.

I have been sending and receiving happily in the last few hours since - so I remain confused.

(Windows 7 Enterprise).

Comment: Double-clicking the offline icon at botttom-left does nothing.

Answer (score 2):

I just had this problem too. It turned out to be an "unresponsive script" dialogue displayed just off the screen so I couldn't see it. Some things seemed to work in Thunderbird, so it *appeared* like it was running as normal, and the dialogue box was not modal, but other threads were - I guess - queued behind me responding to the dialogue.

Killing the warning dialogue from Task Manager got everything flow again.

Answer (score 1):

Well, sitting with Thunderbird closed for a few hours and starting it using the Profile Manager seems to have resolved the situation - I am no longer working offline. Starting Thunderbird via the profile manager is [discussed here](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_Manager). I created an empty second profile, unchecked "Don't Ask on startup" and selected my original default profile.

It was either a problem with the profile or an unrelated condition. I'm posting this as a pointer,

Comment: This is old thread, but perfect advice to kill the Thunderbird process in Windows Task Manager. It sorted my offline issue out very easily, so thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem and resolved it by closing Thunderbird, killing the process in the Windows Task Manager (it didn't disappear on its own) and then re-starting Thunderbird. All is good again.

The solution was on http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=39&t=1812665 (found via Google).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and resolved disabling automatic offline mode detection which sometimes triggers when there are network problems:

http://www.zezore.com/2010/02/18/troubleshootings/how-to-turn-off-automatic-offline-mode-in-thunderbird/

Comment: Please add a bit more detail, a summary of the linked page would be useful.

Comment: The link is dead.